# Confusion about primary decomposition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, affine-varieties

I'm anaysing the primary decomposition of $I=(x^3(y-1), x^2y(y-1), xy^2(y-1))\subset k[x,y]$ (where $k$ is an algebraicaly closed field). Here is what I've found:

$$I=(x)\cap(y-1)\cap(x, y)^3$$

If this is correct, it means $(x), (y-1)$ and $(x, y)$ are the associated primes of $I$, where $(x), (y-1)$ are isolated and $(x,y)$ is embedded.

Here's a remark from page $52$ in Atiyah-Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*:

> The names isolated and embedded come from geometry. Thus if $A=k[x_1,...,x_n]$, where $k$ is a field, the ideal $\mathfrak a$ gives rise to a variety $X \subset k^n$. The minimal primes $p_i$ corresponds to the irreducible components of $X$ and the embedded primes corresponds to subvarieties of these, i.e., varieties embedded in the irreducible components.

By looking at $V(I)$ (which is the union of the lines $x=0$ and $y=1$), we get that $V(x)=\{x=0\}$ and $V(y-1)=\{y=1\}$ are the irreducible components (which is what I expected), but the embedded variety is $V(x, y)=\{(0,0)\}$, which was confusing to me. By his explanation, I was expecting to find the embedded subvariety $V(x,y-1)=\{(0,1)\}$, which is embedded in both components, so this point $(0,0)$ seemed kind of random to me.

Why is $(0,0)$ special, geometricaly speaking? Why does it show up instead of $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1):

You ask: *"Why is $(0,0)$ special?"* - it is not special, your ideal is just so that the corresponding scheme simply *has* an embedded component at $(0,0)$. For example, if you consider the ideal
$$J:=(x)\cap(y-1)\cap(x,y-1)^2
= (xy^2-xy, x^2y)$$
instead, you get a different ideal which also has the components $\{y=1\}$ and $\{x=0\}$ as well as an embedded component at $(0,1)$. More generally, if you consider the ideal
$$(x)\cap(y-1)\cap(x,y-b)^2,$$
you will have the same components $\{y=1\}$ and $\{x=0\}$ and an embedded component at $(0,b)$. You can have embedded component(s) anywhere on the lines $\{y=1\}$ and $\{x=0\}$ by simply constructing the corresponding ideal to be the appropriate intersection.

Comment: I'm not sure I got this answer: you change the primary decomposition, and then what? Want to say that the variety is the same?

Comment: @user26857: I tried to be more clear. Did this help?

Comment: I'd leave the OP to answer. But it's well known that knowing the variety of an ideal rarely tells something about the primary decomposition of the ideal.